# Discord.js keep sending the same message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this piece of code and what I am trying to do is to get info from a JSON file and send it to the discord server. The problem is that it keeps sending the same message again and again.

```js
async function fetch12(message, channel) {
    url[0] = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItemspart=snippet&maxResults=2&playlistId=UUxVDmCmgQMTUTWMeRZUYliw&key=${api_key}`;
    url[1] = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=2&playlistId=UUM_fQdoc0Jmd5mH3KLaDaXA&key=${api_key}`;
    for (let skat = 0; skat < 2; skat++) {
        var link_url = await fetch(url[skat]);
        var fetched = await link_url.json();
        search1 = JSON.stringify(fetched, null, 2);
        await new_vid(message, channel);
    }
}

function new_vid(message, channel) {
    sa++;
    console.log(sa);
    videoId();
    new_link = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video_link[0]}`; //works
    get_channel_name();
    date();
    console.log("!start was activated");
    if (last_date != dates[0] && new_link != last_link) {
        last_date = dates[0];
        last_link = new_link;
        client.on("message", (message) => {
            message.channel.send(`New video/live from ${channel_name}`);
            message.channel.send(new_link);
        });
    }
}

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "!*start") {
        setInterval(() => {
            fetch12(message, channel);
        }, 600000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a loop with the message event over here:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  message.channel.send(`New video/live from ${channel_name}`);
  message.channel.send(new_link);
});
```

Because you sending a message triggers the message event which causes it to respond with sending the message again, so to fix it you can just check if the author of the message is a bot like this:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  message.channel.send(`New video/live from ${channel_name}`);
  message.channel.send(new_link);
});
```